# Prevent solr from using specific synonyms in query

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm trying to get documents with word "złoto"(gold) in them.
My query looks like this

```
"querystring":"content:złoto"
"parsedquery":"SynonymQuery(Synonym(content:złoto content:złoty))"
```

"złoty" is a synonym for "złoto" (inflection to be more specific) but it is also a synonym for "zł"(currency). Word "zł" is far more popular in indexed content, so when I'm trying to get docs with "złoto"(gold) I get more results with "zł"(which is not what I'm looking for).

I have "zł" word in my stopwords file and my field definition looks like this

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Is there a way to get solr to look only for specific synonyms for given word, for example:

```
"złoto" => ["złota", "złoty"] but not "zł"(which is synonym for "złoty")
```

?

I'm using solr 6.2.0.